# How do I specify in which database my schema should be created?

Tags: 7, database

When using [multiple databases](http://drupal.org/node/18429) in Drupal 7, how can I specify that a table is to be created in a different database on a different server?

By default, when you install a module, Drupal assumes that everything in `hook_schema()` should be installed in the default database. Is there a way to specify that a table should be created on a different database, or is there some kind of manual workaround I can use?

Comment: My initial thought is that you can't do this at the API level. Reason being that your module would be tied to a specific and rare database configuration. I assume this is a site specific module? I believe your fix will also need to be site/db-configuration specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is an official API; it doesn't make much sense to do this in general.

That said, all you need to do is give your `hook_schema` a different name than `yourmodule_schema` (basically whatever you want, like `yourmodule_schema_otherdb`) and then in hook_install(), first [switch your database](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_set_active/7), then replicate what [drupal_install_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_install_schema/7) does except that you call your custom schema definition function and then switch the database back to the default.

Also, remember to implement `hook_uninstall()`.

No idea why you'd want to do this, though. :)

Comment: The purpose (in this case) is sharding, but I can think of lots of valid reasons you'd do this.
Given how much trouble it would be working around this shortcoming, I think I’ll end up just writing a buch of `CREATE TABLE` statements for this.

Comment: For which you will need to write corresponding hook_uninstall() as well if you want to do it properly :) Not sure I see the troubles you're talking about, all you need to do is implement hook_enable (which you had to do in 6.x as well) and copy and adjust the few lines of code in drupal_install_schema(). Especially if you want your tables to show up in multiple databases, you can even use hook_schema() to have it in the default database and in hook_install() do it for the other databases as well. You might even be able to simply call drupal_install_schema($yourmodule) between switching the db.

Answer (score 11):

I have achieved this with the information provided by [Berdir](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/31/berdir). My code looks like:

```
<?php
function mymodule_schema_otherdb() {
  $schema['mytable'] = array(
    'description' => 'My table description',
    'fields' => array(
      'myfield' => array(
        'description' => 'My field description',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'size' => 'medium',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('myfield'),
  );
  return $schema;
}

function mymodule_install() {
  db_set_active('otherdb');
  $schema = mymodule_schema_otherdb();
  foreach ($schema as $name => $table) {
    db_create_table($name, $table);
  }
  db_set_active();
}

function mymodule_uninstall() {
  db_set_active('otherdb');
  $schema = mymodule_schema_otherdb();
  foreach ($schema as $name => $table) {
    db_drop_table($name);
  }
  db_set_active();
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't be too much work to get a module that looks for that hook and fires on install and uninstall. with  other db being a key of the schema structure

Comment: @JeremyFrench, does this setup require the empty database to be created in advance?  I am assuming so.

Answer (score 1):

A **Drupal 8** version of the *.install file [code](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/51673/28700) provided by @Елин Й.:

Note: Database must exist and be specified in settings.php.

```
<?php
function mymodule_schema_otherdb() {
  $schema['mytable'] = array(
    'description' => 'My table description',
    'fields' => array(
      'myfield' => array(
        'description' => 'My field description',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'size' => 'medium',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('myfield'),
  );
  return $schema;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function mymodule_install() {
  \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection('otherdb');
  $connection = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection();

  $schema = mymodule_schema_shared();
  foreach ($schema as $name => $table) {
    $connection->schema()->createTable($name, $table);
  }

  \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();
}

/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */
function mymodule_uninstall() {
  \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection('otherdb');
  $connection = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection();

  $schema = mymodule_schema_shared();
  foreach ($schema as $name => $table) {
    $connection->schema()->dropTable($name);
  }

  \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();
}
```

Here's a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/laradevitt/8a9f07860f5bd3e088c6).

Answer (score -2):

In Settings.php
`$db_url=array('default'=>$db_url, 'sec_db'=>$sec_db_url);`
In `hook_schema` `db_set_active('sec_db')` will now connect to your another DB , *not sure if this is recommended or not try it at your own risk.*
And you can make use of db_prefix to query from this secondary DB.
You can make use db prefix in settings.php

Comment: That would be system wide though, which the OP can already do

Comment: what would be system wide ? please clarify

Comment: These semantics (`$db_url`, `$db_prefix` as a global setting are for Drupal 6. And the dot-notation only works when using a different database on the same MySQL server, not when (as in my case) you're accessing different servers.

Comment: @kantu OP is asking how to change the database for a specific table. Your original solution (before you edited) would have made the change system-wide, not on a table-by-table basis.

Comment: Using $db_url you should be able to connect to multiple DBs as well as multiple servers.

Comment: And as I mentioned before, there is no `$db_url` or a global `$db_prefix` variable in Drupal 7, and even if there were, it would not solve the problem.

Comment: When `hook_schema()` is called, Drupal is not necessarily creating the database tables used from the module; `hook_schema()` is also invoked from `drupal_write_record()`. Setting a different database without setting back the previously used one is bad practice.