# Hook_schema and multiple databases

Tags: database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I specify in which database my schema should be created?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24550/how-do-i-specify-in-which-database-my-schema-should-be-created)

I would like to create an entity module which discuss with another Drupal database.

In my module.install, this is ok :

```
db_set_active('otherdb');
if (!db_table_exists('mytable')) {
$result = db_query("CREATE TABLE mytable (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     title VARCHAR(255)
   );");
drupal_set_message("LOG :Creation of table mytable ok");
}
db_set_active();
```

but this can't be done with hook_schema  :

```
$schema['mytable'] = array (
'description' => 'The main store for our entity',
'fields' => array(
  'mytable_id' => array(
    'description' => 'Primary key for our table of mytable',
    'type' => 'serial',
    'unsigned' => TRUE,
    'not null' => TRUE,
  ),
  'title' => array(
    'description' => 'The mytable title',
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => '255',
    'not null' => TRUE
  ),
),
'primary key' => array('mytable_id'),
);
db_set_active('otherdb');
return $schema;
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: See the question that I marked this a duplicate of. There is no official API of this, the idea is that the tables a module defines are created in the main database, external database are in most cases only queried and not actually created and managed by a Drupal module. My answer there does however provide a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I think another angle to attack the problem would be to implement hook_schema the normal way, as if there was only one database. And then tell Drupal to use another database for some tables in [settings.php](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x:/sites/default/default.settings.php#l142). Your module will not have to be run on seperate databases and all that external database stuff is taken care of by Drupals database layer.